# Get all messages from array - php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to get all messages and put it all into array , but there is another way i want sort all messages by id , for example:
my json :

```
{"msg_c":[{"message":"Hi","sender":"2","receve":"3","name":"Muhamad Bagzada"},{"message":"Hello","sender":"3","receve":"2","name":"Danyal Join"},{"message":"What's up , How are you ?","sender":"2","receve":"3","name":"Muhamad Bagzada"},{"message":"fine and you ?","sender":"3","receve":"2","name":"Danyal Join"},{"message":"fine","sender":"2","receve":"3","name":"Muhamad Bagzada"}]}
```

Exactly i want :

show messgaes in array by different value , **( message_u : my msg , messages_m : his msg)**

```
{
    "msg_c":
    [
        {"message_u":"Hi","sender":"2","receve":"3","name":"Muhamad Bagzada"},
        {"message_m":"Hello","sender":"3","receve":"2","name":"Danyal Join"},
        {"message_u":"What's up , How are you ?","sender":"2","receve":"3","name":"Muhamad Bagzada"},
        {"message_m":"fine and you ?","sender":"3","receve":"2","name":"Danyal Join"},
        {"message_m":"fine","sender":"2","receve":"3","name":"Muhamad Bagzada"}
    ]
}
```

php function :

```
public function MessageApp ($user_id,$sender){
    $data ='';
    $Messg = mysqli_query($this->_join, "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE (`from` = '$sender' AND `to` = '$user_id') OR (`from` = '$user_id' AND `to` = '$sender')  ORDER BY dates ASC LIMIT 12 ");
    while ($m = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Messg)) {

    $from = $m['from'];
    $to = $m['to'];
    $chat = $m['chat'];
    $dates = $m['dates'];
    $id = $m['id'];
    if ($user_id === $sender) {
    $select_id = $to;
    }else{
    $select_id = $from;
    }
    $user = new user($from);
    $fullname = ($user->data()->fname)." ".($user->data()->lname);
    $gettype['msg_c'][] = array(
        'message' => $chat,
        'sender' => $from,
        'receve' => $to,
        'name'=>$fullname
     );

    $data = json_encode($gettype);

    }

    return json_encode($gettype);
}
```

I called json data here :

```
<?php

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/php/core/init.php";
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/php/core/connect.php";
$my_id = input::get('user_id');
$user = new user($my_id);
$sender = $user->data()->id;
$db = db::getInstance();

$message = new message();

$id = input::get("id"); 
$user = new user($id);
$user_id = $user->data()->id;

echo $message->MessageApp($user_id,$sender);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you building the row in msg_c, you can separate the set key in different situation like this

```
 <?php
 $msg_row = array(
     'sender' => $from,
     'receve' => $to,
     'name'=> $fullname
 );
 if ($user_id === $sender) {
     $msg_row['message_m'] = $chat;
 } else {
     $msg_row['message_u'] = $chat;
 }
 $gettype['msg_c'][] = $msg_row;
```

Or even build the array in the if else statement before to reuse the code

Comment: There is many way  , but it's for Android project and parsing json object , when i use ( if else statement ) , json only accept one value from array php